# Custom select list in Laravel Way

Tags: php, select, laravel, laravel-4

I am able to generate the select list in Laravel Way, But how can i insert a custom element in it.

Here is my form:

```
<li>        
<?php
  $countrya[] = 'Country';
?>             
@foreach($countries as $row) 
<?php
$countryarr[$row->CountryID] = $row->Country;
?>
@endforeach 
{{ Form::select('ClientSales', $countryarr, '',
         array('class' => 'choiceSelect fi_top', 'id' => 'CountryName')); }}
</li>
```

Here it will generate the list of countries,

The problem is it will display the first country name in the first list, but i want to insert a dummy value inside it.

i.e., `<option value="">Choose any Country</option>`

How can I do this in Laravel  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is:

```
$countrya[] = 'Country';
```

I don't know what it's and if you use it, but you need here (after / before above line or instead of it):

```
$countryarr[''] = 'Choose any Country';
```

because you use `$countryarr` in your select. You should also create array with data to View rather in controller and not in Blade template

Comment: But here, while i submit the form without choosing any country, it searches for empty result. Should i have have any onclick event to alert for choose any choice like that ?

Comment: You can add JavaScript validation if any other option is selected but also on server side you need to validate it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. When i modify like this $countryarr[] = 'Choose any Country'; It was done. Accepting your answer :)

Comment: I am getting <option value="0">Choose any Country</option> for the Default select, Is there any possiblity i can remove the value=0 ?

Comment: Yes, Thanks, If i use  $countryarr[''] its showing value as '' (null) and if i use $countryarr[] its showing value as '0'. Got it :)

Comment: @BizDev So maybe there is no other option. I used the same (empty value) but I was using for it custom loop and not built-in `Form::select`

Comment: Yes, thanks.. I followed the one you said in answer i mean to use $countryarr['']

Comment: Hi i have posted a question. can you solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990844/laravel-option-select-default-issue

Answer (score 1):

Check This one

```
   <li>        
        <?php
          $countrya[] = 'Country';
            $countryarr[0]='Choose any Country'; //Here is the code I have added
        ?>             
        @foreach($countries as $row) 
        <?php
            $countryarr[$row->CountryID] = $row->Country;
        ?>
        @endforeach 
        {{ Form::select('ClientSales', $countryarr, '', array('class' => 'choiceSelect fi_top', 'id' => 'CountryName')); }}
      </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to make your initial item for $countryarr

```
$countryarr = ['Choose any Country'];

It will create <option value="0">Choose any Country</option>
```

So its ID will become zero. Its up to you now how you will evaluate the zero when you submit it.