# Laravel Option Select - Default Issue

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my Select Box, Here All Company will be loaded,

But i want to display the Particular company as **default selected** which i have it in session.

**Here is my Code**

```
$sessioncompany = 'ABCcompany'
$comp[''] = 'Company';
@foreach($company_list as $row) 
        <?php
        $comp[$row->CompanyID] = $row->CompanyName;
        ?>
        @endforeach 
 {{ Form::select('CompanyID', $comp, '', array('id' => 'seCompanyID')); }}
```

What i tried is

```
 {{ Form::select('CompanyID', $comp, '', array('id' => 'seCompanyID'), array(id=>$sessioncompany)); }}
```

But i ended with failure

What is the mistake i am doing and How can i fix that ?

Note : I want it in the native laravel  method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$selectedId = ... // get the id from the session
{{ Form::select('CompanyID', $comp, array($selectedId), array('id' => 'seCompanyID')) }}
```

Comment: The $selectedId won't have $ Symbol inside the Form ??

Comment: @BizDev You're not passing `value` but its `id` (array index)

Answer (score 4):

The `Form::select()` method has the following parameters:

- `$name` - the `name`HTML attribute
- `(array) $list` - the list of options, key-value pairs for actual value => displayed value
- `$selected` - the selected item's value
- `(array) $options` - any extra HTML attributes, as per other Form/HTML helper methods

So, the third parameter `$selected` is the one you want to pass your session value to. Copying your example and replacing:

```
{{ Form::select('CompanyID', $comp, Session::get('my_session_var'), array('id' => 'seCompanyID')); }}
```

Where `'my_session_var'` is the name of the session variable you store the value of the item that should be selected by default.

The great thing about using Laravel's Form helpers is that you get the 'old' input for free. For example, if you set a default here and the user changes it, submits the form and there's a validation error. When the form is redisplayed (assuming you redirected back with `return Redirect::back()->withInput();`) the value the user selected, rather than your explicit default will be set.

(Thanks to @JarekTkaczyk for putting me right on the old input thing.)

Comment: You don't need that `Input::old(...)` at all. Laravel will populate the form in this order: Old input, bound data, explicit value in the helper. That said, when the form is repopulated, then old input will be there anyway.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Old input only gets populated if the `$selected` parameter is `null`, right? But if it's `null`, we can't set a fallback for 'no old input'.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's not getting repopulated only when you pass `null`. **it works always** no matter what is the default value passed to the helper. Try with model binding, this is the best case to test it.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't realise that. I'd better go and look at some of the code I've written. I think I've done some on the assumption that providing an explicit value will always work. Either that or I'm just going a bit crazy today.

Comment: Ahh I've just looked at the code. You're (kinda) right of course: the order is old input, explicit data, bound data in the case of model binding. That's okay. I think I just had a brain fart - I rely on the explicit value overriding bound data and kinda took that to also mean it overrides old data. I'll update my answer so I don't provide misinformation then.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I suppose it has been fixed, the order is like in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong parameters. max parameters should be 4. Try this:

```
{{ Form::select('CompanyID', array('default' => $sessioncompany)+$comp, 'default') }}
```

Comment: `$comp` is the options you are populating first.

Comment: Why does every answer for this use + when it states "Unsupported operand types"

Answer (score 0):

Just beware, if you're on a page with the form with the select box, make sure that with each page refresh while testing you do a full page refresh without using cache - `Ctrl + Shift + R`, otherwise the last selected value may remain selected.